# Changing the file extension using PHP

Tags: php, file-extension

Is it "good" to change an image file extension?

For instance, I have a `jpg` file inputed, and I change it to a `png`. Is this OK or should I leave it as a `jpg`?

I use the `rename()` to change the name and the file extension.

It is related to PHP, because I do my renaming with PHP with a upload script.

Another question is: Is it safe to do it e.g can the files become corrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing an image file extension from `.jpg` to `.png` does not change it to a PNG file.  It just changes the name of the file.  This does not change the contents of the file at all, so it does not become corrupt.  It only changes the name of it.

Comment: thanks for your help, i thought this was the case but i thought it was best to check

Answer (score 2):

Leave file names with the appropriate extension, or you will confuse everyone, including yourself.

No, the file cannot become corrupt... a file name is just the name.

Never allow users to dictate the names of files on your system.  No matter what they upload, rename it to something with no extension, and store the files outside of the web server's doc root.  You don't want them uploading `.php` scripts and what not.

Comment: yer ok. they wont be able to upload anything except images as i filter it through JavaScript before i give it to any php file, just for safety, just as you said.

Comment: Your JavaScript is meaningless.  It's executed client side.

Comment: yes but it doesn't do anything with the files and the only time they can upload a php script is through ftp which is a potability, but no ones except me knows the password for it.

Comment: Unless you're checking those uploads server-side, they can upload whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the extension of file is just renaming it. The extension serves the purpose of merely defining the data type that the file contains.

Renaming a JPEG file into a PNG is therefore a very bad idea. Although some image viewers may still be able to figure out that your PNG is actually JPEG and view it correctly, others will not.

Use [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) or [GD 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) to do any image conversions in PHP.